# Is there a way to back up Tomboy Notes?

Tags: tomboy

I have some class notes and relatively important stuff that I have saved in Tomboy Notes.  I need to wipe my Ubuntu 10.10 and install the newest version of Ubuntu.  I already have a dual-partition Windows machine.  Is there a way for me to copy all of my notes/save them elsewhere before I reinstall the Ubuntu operating system?

Comment: If you are formatting your Ubuntu partition, I recommend to make a separate home partition so that you won’t need to backup your data on the future installations. :)

Answer (score 6):

Tomboy Notes uses the `/home/user/.local/share/tomboy/` directory. Make sure that you have the ability to view hidden files.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to display all the hidden folders and files contained in the home folder.  So you can copy the contents of that folder to a different location or back it up using your favorite backup software.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I want to add this answer for those who shall face this issue in future.

Tomboy( i have version 1.15.4) has the option of synchronizing notes. So, if you have dropbox installed, you can take help of this feature to synchronize your notes in dropbox. Then when you reinstall tomboy and again specify the synchronization folder, all the notes will get synced.